# how to get data annotations of the entityobject to viewmodel object without mentioning it again in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

i have been stuck with a problem where i have to use annotations on my viewmodel also

for example my entityobject is User in the designer class (Teamwork.Designer.cs)

Suppose i have the data annotations written on User_Name and User_Password

```
 [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 User_Pk
    {
        get
        {
            return _User_Pk;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_User_Pk != value)
            {
                OnUser_PkChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("User_Pk");
                _User_Pk = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("User_Pk");
                OnUser_PkChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _User_Pk;
    partial void OnUser_PkChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnUser_PkChanged();


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your name")]
    [StringLength(20,ErrorMessage="Name cannot exceed 20 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 \.\&\'\-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid name")]
    public global::System.String User_Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _User_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUser_NameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("User_Name");
            _User_Name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("User_Name");
            OnUser_NameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _User_Name;
    partial void OnUser_NameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnUser_NameChanged();


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Email(ErrorMessage="Invalid email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter email address")]
    public global::System.String User_Mail_Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _User_Mail_Id;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUser_Mail_IdChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("User_Mail_Id");
            _User_Mail_Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("User_Mail_Id");
            OnUser_Mail_IdChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _User_Mail_Id;
    partial void OnUser_Mail_IdChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnUser_Mail_IdChanged();


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter password")]
    [StringLength(20,ErrorMessage="Password cannot exceed 20 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 \.\&\'\-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid password")]
    public global::System.String User_Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _User_Password;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUser_PasswordChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("User_Password");
            _User_Password = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("User_Password");
            OnUser_PasswordChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _User_Password;
    partial void OnUser_PasswordChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnUser_PasswordChanged();


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.DateTime User_Creation_Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _User_Creation_Date;
        }
        set
        {
            OnUser_Creation_DateChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("User_Creation_Date");
            _User_Creation_Date = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("User_Creation_Date");
            OnUser_Creation_DateChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.DateTime _User_Creation_Date;
    partial void OnUser_Creation_DateChanging(global::System.DateTime value);
    partial void OnUser_Creation_DateChanged();


    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Boolean Is_Active
    {
        get
        {
            return _Is_Active;
        }
        set
        {
            OnIs_ActiveChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Is_Active");
            _Is_Active = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("Is_Active");
            OnIs_ActiveChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Boolean _Is_Active;
    partial void OnIs_ActiveChanging(global::System.Boolean value);
    partial void OnIs_ActiveChanged();

    #endregion
```

now i have created a viewmodel for the above User : EntityObject 
with name RegisterUserViewModel.cs as below

```
 public class RegisterUserViewModel
 {
   public int UserId{get;set;}
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string UserEmail { get; set; }
   public string UserPassword { get; set;}
 }
```

the entity object is created in separate folder named Teamwork.Data
and the viewmodel created in the folder Teamwork.BusinessLogic

now in my controller action i have called a method which is defined in Teamwork.Businesslogic as below

'

```
public ViewResult Register(string invite)
    {
            SignUpAndLogin signLog = new SignUpAndLogin();
            var model = signLog.GetRegisterModel();
            return View(model);

    }
```

SignUpLogin.cs is the class that contains all my business related operations in the Teamwork.BusinessLogic folder which has GetRegisterModel as below

```
  public RegisterUserViewModel GetRegisterModel()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, RegisterUserViewModel>();
        User user = new User();
        RegisterUserViewModel model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User,      RegisterUserViewModel>(user);
        return model;
    }'
```

i have mapped RegisterviewModel object with User object and i m returning it to the action that called the above method.(please can anyone say this the correct way of mapping?)

My problem is i have to mention the annotation again in the RegisterViewModel(even after mapping?) like below for the annotation to work

```
 public class RegisterUserViewModel
 {
   public int UserId{get;set;}
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter the Name")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string UserEmail { get; set; }
   public string UserPassword { get; set;}
 }
```

Can anybody please say my mapping is correct or not and any way to avoid duplication of data annotaion in view model

The question is long and may be dumb..but this is the problem i have been facing for 2 days now...
Can anyone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should edit Teamwork.Designer.cs with your custom code.  That file will most probably get overwritten if you make changes to the database and then regenerate Teamwork.edmx for example.

Just add the data annotations to your view model.

The Automapper mapping seems like it would give you an error because the property names are different between the source and destination objects.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, RegisterUserViewModel>()
.ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.UserName, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(sourceMember => sourceMember.User_Name)
.ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.UserPassword, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(sourceMember => sourceMember.User_Password)
.ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.UserEmail, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(sourceMember => sourceMember.User_Mail_Id)
.ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.UserId, memberOptions => memberOptions.MapFrom(sourceMember => sourceMember.User_Pk);
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: Thanks Rami u have given me a valuable information ....You have given a clear idea how to use Automapper too..THanks a lot